# Writing - another phrase that could replace "goes beyond all bounds of decency"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, correlative-comparatives

I am tasked with paraphrasing the writing of others who are substantially better writers than I am. The goal is to keep the language as objectively similar as possible.

Just to clarify, "goes beyond all bounds of decency" is referring to someone's conduct. 'Conduct' may be used before the new phrase. Additional descriptors would be "utterly intolerable" or "no person should be expected to endure it."

Additionally, the part I'm struggling with is mainly "all bounds." Suggestions on words to use in its place would be helpful.

Comment: _His conduct is egregious_. Or _His conduct scandalizes_.

Comment: It seems an odd task, I'm curious. Are you trying to avoid copyright?

Comment: goes beyond all bounds = goes beyond every boundary = goes beyond every limit -> exceeds all the limits [of decency]

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica more of an ethical duty to avoid plagiarism in this field. In this case, many people have used the exact language. It's not necessarily wrong to do so, but I'm trying to avoid it anyway.

Comment: so far outside of what could be considered decent

Comment: It’s a phrase used in court decisions with some description of what it doesn’t include, namely rudeness, insults, hurt feelings, etc. Are you sure you want to change it? To what purpose?

Comment: @Xanne Txs for your honesty, but I still don't see your point. The OP is asking for a word or phrase to describe "conduct" that "goes beyond all bounds of decency".

Comment: @Xanne A similar comment. If you don't like answers, clarify your viewpoint by suggesting a better rather than expressing mere opinion. Downmarking reasonable possibilities is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: Anton, this is a term used in law. The options are not in fact reasonable possibilities.

Comment: If the OP actually wanted _legal_ language only, it should have been specified in the Q. We have a tag [legalese]. @Xanne

Comment: @Xanne perhaps OP has already stated the legal verdict, using the expression for that purpose. It seems quite reasonable to ask for another phrase in a discussion, to avoid too much repetition.

Comment: See https://www.lawcjb.com/infliction-of-emotional-distress/.  No, I don't think substituting other terms for terms that have been carefully defined in legal cases is a reasonable use of avoiding repetition.

Comment: @Xanne The term used in courts of law might be more precisely "to go/to be  beyond all possible bounds of decency": https://www.casemine.com/search/us/beyond%2Ball%2Bpossible%2Bbounds%2Bof%2Bdecency; nevertheless the phrase "beyond all  bounds of decency" has been used in others contexts, although not often : https://books.google.fr/books?id=aGdGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22beyond+all+bounds+of+decency%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5mYaotfHsAhXQzIUKHbk1AoEQ6AEwAXoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22beyond%20all%20bounds%20of%20decency%22&f=false (1/2)

Comment: @Xanne https://books.google.fr/books?id=o3N-RBPcg5QC&pg=RA2-PA103&dq=%22beyond+all+bounds+of+decency%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5mYaotfHsAhXQzIUKHbk1AoEQ6AEwBnoECFcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22beyond%20all%20bounds%20of%20decency%22&f=false (2/2)

Comment: @Xanne - I am indeed talking about IIED, but the reason I did not mention that in the post is because I wanted to see what came to people's minds when they saw those words. I'm discussing the outrageous element, therefore I would only use that phrase when initially quoting it. Consequently, Cascabel is correct; I did not want to limit it. (P.s. this is my first time on the website, I didn't know legalese was a tag, but should have guessed. Noted!)

Answer (score 3):

***beyond the pale***

> To be 'beyond the pale' is to be unacceptable; ***outside agreed standards of decency.***

[-phrases.org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beyond-the-pale.html)

Ex.

"Himmler's  conduct had gone beyond the pale, and he could expect no mercy from the Nuremberg court."

---

I have heard it used in [court decisions.](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=XhdaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA365&dq=%22went%20beyond%20the%20pale%22%20legal%20decisions&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitqdSkuPHsAhVGwlkKHfnaBPsQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22went%20beyond%20the%20pale%22%20legal%20decisions&f=false)

> ... here no court reporter was used , but without deciding whether the taking of a sworn statement or questionnaire alone ... sworn questionnaire on the same questions , coupled with the anti - union animus present , it ***went beyond the pale of ...***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are quite a few choices, but I suspect many more can be found.

- His/her conduct is **unforgivable/unpardonable/inexcusable/unacceptable**.
- **objectionable beyond compare**.
- His/her conduct goes beyond what's **acceptable/tolerable**.
- all reasonable limits.
- all reasonable bounds.
- the limits of acceptable behaviour. ([ref.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go-beyond))
- the limits of what can be condoned. ([ref.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condone))

Answer (score 0):

From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cross+the+line),

> Their behaviour **crosses the line** [of acceptability].